# What's the best website to locate the ip's country using php script

Tags: php, flags

this website does not work anymore http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip= . it gives me fasle statement like XX . Can i get a website which it gives me full country name 
Like = 111.111.11.11 => United Kingdom

Comment: This type of question is off topic, but look into the maxmind database.

Answer (score 0):

This service will good for you, response is serialized data

> http://ip-api.com/php/111.111.11.11

You can read;
http://ip-api.com/docs/api:serialized_php

Simple usage;

```
$data = unserialize(
    file_get_contents(
        'http://ip-api.com/php/111.111.11.11'
    )
    , ['allowed_classes' => false]
);
var_dump($data['country']);
```

Comment: First of all , i want only the country name , Second of all , check this ip( of facebook ) 31.13.80.36 it's from canada but the website says it's from France

Comment: that's not even my question

Comment: No this ip from France, look; https://apps.db.ripe.net/db-web-ui/#/query?bflag=true&source=GRS&searchtext=31.13.80.36#resultsSection

Comment: so why it gives me XX http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=31.13.80.36

Comment: This API seems working not good, i checked for my ip http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php, response is {"country_name":"(Unknown Country?)","country_code":"XX","city":"(Unknown City?)","ip":"???"}

Comment: i propose you, use another API, it will be save your time

Comment: Give me a suggestion

Comment: i don't know how many queries limit you need, I have already written to you an api

Comment: the responce is always Array

Comment: i used ur script . It always gives me Array

Comment: Yes, as on documentation you will get array. If you want to use object, just add before the variable (object). For example $data = (object)$data; echo $data->country ?? 'Not found';

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to install the [GeoIP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php)? [`geoip_region_by_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-region-by-name.php) should make the trick.